# Should we have a badge / recognition of well-cited answers? Questions?

Tags: feature-request, tags, reputation, badges

[It has been said](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/564/citations-are-the-source-code-of-physics-stackexchange) that "citations are the source code of Physics.SE"

References are how citations are added to a posting.  Should we recognize good citation/reference practices via:

- a badge after a fixed number of answers, voted to N-score, each with at least X references
- a badge when total citations in all answers exceed Y
- when a moderator awards Q or A with subjectively-good ('policy') references.
- etc.

By 'counting citations', I mean "counting the number of links that are included in the body of the question or answer"

Comment: By _a citation_ you mean _a link from another Phys.SE post?_

Comment: I was thinking a link to a qualified web source that provide information about the answer, or a facet of the answer.  E.G. a peer-reviewed journal link, pub-sci article, univ. website, wikipedia, etc.

Comment: How are you in practice going to count outside citations of a Phys.SE post?

Comment: @Qmechanic edited above

Comment: Do you mean _references_ rather than _citations?_

Comment: @Qmechanic I do.  On this site, I think of the best references being citations.  I realize this isn't a comprehensive mindset.  I've opened the the question to solicit answeres with ideal solutions

Comment: Usually _references_ and _citations_ of a given post are two different things. A given post can include several _references_ to outside articles. Conversely, outside articles can _cite_ a given post. They become _citations_ of the given post, but are obviously for chronological reasons not mentioned in the post.

Comment: If someone answered a question, and references 4 journal articles, are those references *not* citations of the articles?  The answer given is supported by the referenced (cited) articles.

Comment: AFAIK they don't make site-specific badges on SE. Doesn't hurt to ask, though.

Comment: [I just did](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/176643/should-we-have-a-badge-recognition-of-well-cited-answers-questions) and got the *hit-storm.  You'd think I kicked a puppy.

Comment: Besides the "should we do this" and "will they let us do this" aspects, there's the cold, hard, "this is too complicated to be done" aspect - all badges are currently awarded through infrequently-updated counters on the site that track votes, views, and postings. Trivial algorithms, fully automated; no gray areas; no hassle.

Comment: Also if this is implemented, I request a gold badge for the [time I went on a citation binge](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/59348/10851) :P

Comment: The answer you liked is the kind of answer that I think we would benefit from by drawing more attention

Comment: This is a terribly mis-written post. "well-cited" means that many people have cited it              "lot of references" is the right word here.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect tracking external citations would be impractical, but I quite like the idea of an internal citation count. Having said this, frequently cited questions tend to attract high scores so the author gets credit that way.

@NewAlexandria: you shouldn't interpret all the comments as a *hit-storm. Rather the reverse actually, as if a question attracts a lot of discussion it usually means it's a good question.

Comment: Certainly a well-cited answer can become highly ranked, but the well-cited questions have a specific worth.  Maybe the traditional journals already worked this out, and what we really need is our own version of Impact Factor.

Comment: Note that official Impact Factor calculations are not a big thing in all fields, especially the less cutthroat [read: more pleasant ;) ] ones.